# Error with basic textField actionListener (Error when commands are in the listener)

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, actionlistener, jtextfield

I keep getting an error (Will post error below) When I press enter on my text field. I want the text field to save the data to a globally defined variable. The actionListener works whenever I don't include 'name' in my code, for example if I put int a = 3 then there are no errors. I have also declared name globally (on the main gui) because if I don't I get an error saying the variable is not in the scope, maybe this is an issue?

```
    //Declared inside the main gui (the others are nested in this)
    JTextField name;
    JLabel nameLabel;

    //Name text field defined inside the gui jInternalFrame
    TextField name = new TextField("Enter Name..", 20);
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel();
    nameLabel.setText("Name: ");
    name.addActionListener(new nameListener());
    addRoomPanel.add(nameLabel);
    addRoomPanel.add(name);`

    //ActionListener defined outside of the text field gui
    class nameListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            nameString = name.getText();
            name.setText("saved");
            name.selectAll();
         }
    }

ERROR MESSAGE:
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at InternalFrame$dobListener.actionPerformed(InternalFrame.java:445)
    at java.awt.TextField.processActionEvent(TextField.java:617)
    at java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:585)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at  java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Components of the UI are defined twice. Once in the GUI-class as variables, once in the (i suppose) constructor. Due to this two variables with name `name` and `nameLabel` exist. The constructor will access the ones declared in the constructor, thus the variables of the GUI-class remain uninitialized (`null`). The `ActionListener` access the variable in the GUI-class, which is `null` and throws a `NullPointerException`. You'll have to use one variable instead of two. For a more precise answer, i'll need a bit more code (or atleast something more useable than the snippets posted above).

Comment: Perfect! I got it thanks, I moved my definition in the constructor to the GUI-class and it works perfectly.